# MVVM Additional Property for a Field

Tags: c#, mvvm, properties, interface

Maybe you can help me at the following issue.

I have a **Model** like this:

```
public class Lookup
{
    private string _ValueName;
    [Required]
    public string ValueName
    {
        get
        {
            return _ValueName;
        }
        set
        {
            _ValueName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In the ViewModel a can access **Lookup.ValueName** to get the Value of the item. But how i can get the Name of the DataColumn? I want to implement a new interface which will give me the Name but maybe it is a lot easier? I do not want to write the Name hardcoded.

Target is to write: `Lookup.ValueName.DataColumnName`

Thanks for helping
Tom

Comment: What is the data column name? Also, no, you cannot do `Lookup.ValueName.DataColumnName` if you expect `Lookup.ValueName` to be a string.

Comment: The DataColumnName should be "ValueName" in this example. The value of ValueName is not important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this option:

```
public class Lookup
{
    [Required]
    public string ValueName { get; set; }

    public string ValueNameDataColumnName => nameof(ValueName);
}
```

Comment: This looks perfect. Is there an option to get this option for all fields without writing it for every field?

Comment: I don't believe so, no. _You may be able to achieve it using https://github.com/Fody/Fody but it wouldn't be easy._

Comment: If the column name is always just the name of the property, then you can just use `nameof(Lookup.ValueName)` whenever you actually need it without having to have a separate property.

Comment: poke -> PEFECT...thats what i am searching for...i did not know that nameof exists :)

Comment: You could you T4 Templates to generate this code automatically also, but that is a little more complex to set up.